# Redis master-slave connection

Tags: java, redis

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBm52.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v1xj.jpg)As shown in the figure, I don't know why the redis instance opened now is 192.168.0.63 redis, which cannot connect to itself. This problem was caused by the election of the Sentinel cluster. I did not find an instance of slaveof in the configuration file of this instance, but as soon as it was started, it became like the image above. Can anyone tell me why?

I have tried to start the Sentinel cluster again, and this is the only instance at this time. I keep switching master nodes at 127.0.0.1 6379192.168.0.63. The key point is that my native Ip is 192.168.0.63. I switch to each one. The current instance runs on my local machine, that is, 192.168.0.63. It can't even connect to itself. I'm confused.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please consider rephrasing your question.